# Нужна помощь с jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Здравствуйте,разбираюсь с jsoup хочу распарсить сайт в котором есть класс родитель и в нем несколько нужных подкласов,как получить в Elements эти покласы?

```
            <div class="col-md-8 col-left">
                    <div class="pick-full-load">
                        .......
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        ........
                    </div>
                    <a name="1362915"></a>

                    <div class="card card-hover card-visited job-link">
                        ..........
                    </div>
                    <a name="2499926"></a>

                    <div class="card card-hover card-visited job-link card-logotype">
                       ........
                    </div>
                    <a name="2500542"></a>

                    <div class="card card-hover card-visited job-link card-logotype">
                       ......
            </div>
            <a name="2482734"></a>

            <div class="card card-hover card-visited job-link card-logotype">
             .....
            </div>
            <a name="2484993"></a>
```

Comment: можете описать более подробнее? с примерами блоков html

Comment: @iGreetYou поправил,выложил код с сайта,некоторое ненужное удалил,дабы обьём был поменьше

Comment: @user229233, напишите селекторы тех элементов которые вы хотите получить или хотя бы словесно расскажите.

Comment: @iGreetYou мне по сути нужно 2 класса это card card-hover card-visited job-link 
и

Comment: @iGreetYou card card-hover card-visited job-link card-logotype
а потом у этих классов заберу нужные елементы

Comment: @user229233, старайтесь проставлять более понятные заголовки вопросам - в нынешнем виде заголовок не несёт в себе сути вопроса - это плохо ибо не соответствует целям ресурса. В этом случае следовало написать что-то типа `Как получить список детей элемента через JSOUP`

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае должно быть так:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
Elements elements = document.select("div.col-md-8.col-left > card card-hover.card-visited.job-link.card-logotype");
```